# Add string to end of every tuple in a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this list of tuples;

```
List = [('1', 'John', '129', '37'), ('2', 'Tom', '231', '23')]
```

I want to add a string to the end of every tuple inside this list. It will look like this;

```
OutputList = [('1', 'John', '129', '37', 'TestStr'), ('2', 'Tom', '231', '23', 'TestStr')]
```

I tried `OutputList = [xs + tuple('TestStr',) for xs in List ]` but it did not work out. What is the proper way to solve this?

I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a 1-element tuple, that's `('TestStr',)`, not `tuple('TestStr',)`:

```
OutputList = [xs + ('TestStr',) for xs in List]
```

`tuple('TestStr',)` is the same as `tuple('TestStr')`, since trailing commas are ignored in function calls. `tuple('TestStr')` treats `'TestStr'` as an iterable and builds a tuple containing the characters of the string.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `tuple` part:

```
OutputList = [xs + ('TestStr',) for xs in List]
```

You don't need to the `tuple()` callable here, you are not converting one type to a tuple, all you need is a tuple literal here.

Demo:

```
>>> List = [('1', 'John', '129', '37'), ('2', 'Tom', '231', '23')]
>>> [xs + ('TestStr',) for xs in List]
[('1', 'John', '129', '37', 'TestStr'), ('2', 'Tom', '231', '23', 'TestStr')]
```